Possible to trigger pipeline with multiple job in one stage?
I have created a pipeline job that call another job that has multiple choices.
Below is the code snippet
stage('Deployment Components') {
            when {
                    expression {
                        return (params.SKIP_DEPLOY == false && params.BUILD_TYPE == 'install')
                    }
            }
            steps {
                    script {
                        deploy_components('install',PROFILE_CONFIGURATION_TO_PASS,'integrationA','master','stable_version')
                        deploy_components('install',PROFILE_CONFIGURATION_TO_PASS,'integration','master','stable_version')
                        deploy_components('install',PROFILE_CONFIGURATION_TO_PASS,'realm','master','stable_version')
            }
    }

and calling
def deploy_components(String action,String profile_configuration,String component,String branch, String environment) {
        try {
                checkJob = build job: 'Deploy/master', wait: true,
                parameters: [
                            string(name: 'BUILD_TYPE', value: action ),
                            string(name: 'REMOTE_PROFILE', value: profile_configuration),
                            string(name: 'COMPONENT', value: component),
                            string(name: 'BRANCH', value: branch),
                            string(name: 'ENVIRONMENT',value: environment)
                            ]
                result = checkJob.result
            }
        catch (Error e) {
                    println e
            }
}

But it doesnt go to the next COMPONENT : integration. It stop at first one only.
Is jenkins not supported?

See that wait: true? It means that the upstream pipeline will wait for the first downstream pipeline to finish before triggering the second one. Does it trigger the first pipeline successfully? Does it complete?

Yes the first pipeline able to execute sucessfully. but it stop and not continue to the next pipeline.

By "it stop" do you mean that the upstream pipeline just sits there and waits or that the upstream pipeline completes without triggering other downstream jobs? Do you see any messages in the logs?
